# ActiveMQ: Configure per-destination policy in Java (total ordering)

Tags: configuration, jms, activemq-classic

I have an ActiveMQ embedded broker, along with a number of Topic clients.  Everything is currently configured in Java (rather than XML).  I want to configure total ordering of the topic's messages across clients.

ActiveMQ specifies [total ordering](http://activemq.apache.org/total-ordering.html) as a per-destination policy.  Is there a way to configure this in Java directly?

The vanillaish startup code I've been using:

```
// broker code (single broker)
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
broker.addConnector(address);
broker.setPersistent(false);
broker.setUseJmx(false);
broker.start();

// client code (multiple clients)
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory 
           = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(address);
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();

session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
topic = session.createTopic(topicName);    
producer = session.createProducer(topic);
consumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code would look something like this:

```
    PolicyEntry policy = new PolicyEntry();
    policy.setDispatchPolicy(new StrictOrderDispatchPolicy());

    PolicyMap pMap = new PolicyMap();
    pMap.setDefaultEntry(policy);

    broker.setDestinationPolicy(pMap);
```

Comment: Isn't this solution a default destination policy and not a per-destination policy? Is it possible to setup a destination policy for each individual destination via Java code?